# Python Library for actions on google

Tags: python, node.js, actions-on-google

The package for Node.js for actions on google is [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/nodejs-client-library-release-notes).

Used this, it works fine in getting the app and conversation form google app.

What is the similar library for Python for actions on Google?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no official fulfillment library for Actions on Google. There might be one that is maintained by community members.

If you want to use Python, you could alternatively just respond using JSON messages. The [documentation for Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) has a tab describing the direct JSON responses that you would need to send.

In this way, the Node.js code

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?',
  text: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?',
}));
```

is equivalent to

```
{
  "conversationToken": "",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
        "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?",
                            "displayText": "Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number. What do you have in mind?"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "suggestions": []
            }
        },
        "possibleIntents": [
            {
                "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```